# Crash in getPlaylistWithUUID

Tags: swift, swift2, mpmedialibrary

Am I doing something wrong? This seems pretty simple. It seems getPlaylistWithUUID is calling UUIDString on UUID which ought to work but for some reason the value goes into the method as an NSCFString. This is Swift 2.3

I've filed a bug report but figured I'd also ask here.

```
let name = "playlist name"  
let id:NSUUID = NSUUID()  
let library = MPMediaLibrary()  
let metadata = MPMediaPlaylistCreationMetadata.init(name: name)  
metadata.authorDisplayName = "author"  
metadata.descriptionText = "description"  
library.getPlaylistWithUUID(id, creationMetadata: metadata) { (playlist, error) in  
            if error != nil {  
                if playlist != nil {  
                    NSLog("it works - name:\(playlist!.name)")  
                }  
            }  
}
```

When that runs I get an unrecognized selector crash

```
2016-06-24 10:43:12.563000 bugreport[11008:2243450] -[__NSCFString UUIDString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170276380  
2016-06-24 10:43:12.570185 bugreport[11008:2243450] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString UUIDString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170276380'  
*** First throw call stack:  
(0x187949980 0x186f444bc 0x187950778 0x18794d6e0 0x18784e61c 0x192132114 0x19212eff4 0x1917e3c40 0x19212ef88 0x192131f30 0x1920e74a4 0x100010d2c 0x1000113d8 0x18d6d34c4 0x18d6d301c 0x18d6d9648 0x18d6d6c14 0x18d749528 0x18d955cd0 0x18d95b5e0 0x18d95864c 0x189448010 0x189447e7c 0x189448224 0x1878fa3f0 0x1878f9d38 0x1878f7938 0x18782a2e4 0x18d73e6c4 0x18d739438 0x1000123b8 0x1873cc600)  
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException  
(lldb)
```

This error means that UUIDString is being called on NSCFString instead of UUID. I just wanted to make sure I didn't overlook something, I am passing in the correct Type. For what its worth the same thing happens in Swift 3 using UUID().

(Can someone with enough rep tag this swift2.3 ?)